# Cairngorm Framework

Tags: apache-flex, cairngorm

I want to learn cairngorm framework.  Can any one please suggest to me which tutorial makes it easy to understand the cairngorm framework, and please provide me the links of the tutorial.

Thanks,
Ravi

Comment: there's already a bunch of beginner cairngorm questions on here already...... a simple search before posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links to bookmark:

[Cairngorm Home Page](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/cairngorm/Cairngorm)

Answer (score 0):

[Flex Application Design for Cairngor](http://www.digimmersion.com/support/Flex%20UI%20Design%20For%20Cairngorm.pdf)

[Cairngorm docs](http://www.cairngormdocs.org/)

[Cairngorm 3](http://opensource.adobe.com/wiki/display/cairngorm/Cairngorm+3)

[Davidtucker Blog](http://www.davidtucker.net/category/cairngorm/)

[How to Use Design Patterns](http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/gammadp.html)

[Getting Started With Cairngorm](http://www.bybjorn.com/67/)

Answer (score 0):

These are my favorite Flex links (with a predominantly Java/Spring bias server-side) including Cairngorm 2 & 3
Cairngorm 2 (Part 1 of 5 part video)
http://www.davidtucker.net/2007/10/07/getting-started-with-cairngorm-–-part-1/
Cairngorm 3
(Design patterns)
http://blogs.adobe.com/paulw/ (Presentation Model)
http://blogs.adobe.com/pmartin/ (Presentation Patterns)

Piotr Walczyszyn: Dependency Injection frameworks comparison
http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2010-develop/flexactionscript-30-architecture-and-dependency-injection-frameworks-overview/
https://github.com/pwalczyszyn/MAX-2010-Projects
http://www.riaspace.net/
http://amf.riaspace.com/ (Zend framework back end)
http://www.spicefactory.org/ (Parsley, Pimento (Hibernate-Flex), Cinnamon, Spicelib AS3 libraries)

If you are interested in using Spring-Flex
http://www.springsource.org/spring-flex 
http://coenraets.org/
http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adc-presents/integrating-spring-and-flex/
(or Spring Roo + Flex)
http://blog.springsource.com/author/jgrelle/
Integrating Spring with BlazeDS & LCDS (Jeremy Grelle/Mark Fisher)
http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2009-develop/integrating-spring-with-blazeds-and-livecycle-data-services/
Flex Pesistence with Hibernate (dpHibernate : Mike Nimer)
http://tv.adobe.com/watch/360flex-conference/flex-persistence-with-hibernate-by-mike-nimer/

(These are a bit more trivial)
Using Flex with Java (James Ward)
http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adc-presents/using-flex-with-java/

Remoting with Flex (Kevin Hoyt)
http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adc-presents/remoting-with-flex/

Generate a Flex/J2EE Database App
http://tv.adobe.com/watch/adc-presents/generate-a-flexj2ee-database-application/

Comment: There's also this link http://artinflex.blogspot.com/2010/09/quick-dive-into-parsley-intro-why.html